# Wix toolset. Do custom action on <control> Edit text change

Tags: wix, custom-action

How to perform a custom action in Wix on text change in Edit?

Comment: StackOverflow is a terrible web search tool. Try "How to perform a custom action in Wix on text change in Edit" in your favourite web search.

Comment: What have you done?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you can't. The Windows Installer UI mechanism is rather primitive by modern standards and it does not forward any events when text is changed. That's basically why MSI UI validation is done when a button is clicked and it fires a DoAction event to call a custom action. To quote the documentation for DoAction to call a custom action:

"The DoAction ControlEvent notifies the installer to execute a custom action. This event can be published by a PushButton control, CheckBox control, or a SelectionTree control. This event should be authored into the ControlEvent table."